# How do i deal with this situation for searching records in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am developing a PHP/MYSQL search module, where i have to search tables based on many different criteria, i have some 11 tables, and i have used multiple joins to create one single MySQL query and based on WHERE clause i intend to search for specific records, here is the MYSQL Query that i am using.

```
SELECT
prop.id,
prop.serial,
prop.title,
prop.rating,
prop.addDate,
prop.approve,
prop.status,
prop.user_id as userId,
user_det.email as email,
user_det.name as name,
prop.area_id as areaId,
area.name as areaName,
area.zipCode as zipCode,
area.city_id as cityId,
city.name as cityName,
city.state_id as stateId,
state.name as stateName,
state.country_id as countryId,
country.name as countryName,
prop.subCategory_id as subCategoryId,
subCat.name as subCategoryName,
subCat.category_id as categoryId,
cat.name as categoryName,
prop.transaction_id as transactionId,
trans.name as transactionName,
price.area as landArea,
price.price as priceSqFt,
price.total_price as totalPrice,
features.bedroom,
features.bathroom,
features.balcony,
features.furnished,
features.floorNum,
features.totalFloor
FROM properties prop 
LEFT JOIN user_details user_det ON (prop.user_id = user_det.user_id) 
LEFT JOIN areas area ON (prop.area_id = area.id) 
LEFT JOIN cities city ON (area.city_id = city.id) 
LEFT JOIN states state ON (city.state_id = state.id) 
LEFT JOIN countries country ON (state.country_id = country.id) 
LEFT JOIN subCategories subCat ON (prop.subCategory_id = subCat.id) 
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON (subCat.category_id = cat.id) 
LEFT JOIN transactions trans ON (prop.transaction_id = trans.id) 
LEFT JOIN prop_prices price ON (price.property_id = prop.id) 
LEFT JOIN prop_features features ON (features.property_id = prop.id)
```

although all works well here, i have a situation where i have a table called `prop_amenities` below are the content of this table.

[image]

as the table above have multiple `property_id` if i query it using JOINS then mostly it will return duplicate records or single record omitting others depending on the type of `JOIN` i use. so instead i would like to deal it this way.

use the table prop_amenities to only deal with conditions not to return the result. 
for example i am searching for a property with amenity id 1,5,9,17 and 24, then it should check if all the records exist in the `prop_amenities` table, i.e 1,5,9,17 and 24 in this case. and return the appropriate records with all above selected columns.

i am clueless on dealing this situation using MySQL. how do i go on this?

thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "check if all the records ***exist*** in the `prop_amenities` table" and that's the key word here.

```
SELECT ...
FROM properties AS prop
LEFT JOIN ...
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prop_amenities AS pa WHERE pa.property_id = prop.property_id AND pa.amenity_id = 7);
```